# How to calculate the number of days dynamically (Oracle SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to calculate the number of years, months and days between sysdate and hire_date column considering 28,29,30 and 31 months

i've managed to calculate both the years and months yet i need your help in calculating the days.

Here's the code so far.

`

```
SELECT employee_id, last_name, hire_date,
            trunc(   months_between(sysdate, hire_date) / 12  ) as years,
                    trunc(mod(  months_between(sysdate, hire_date) , 12 ))          as remaining_months
FROM employees;
```

`

Thanks in advance.

I've calculated the years and months and i need help in calculating the days and possibly how to calculate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the number of full months/years that you have already calculated to the `hire_date` and then find the number of days from that to the current date:

```sql
SELECT employee_id,
       last_name,
       hire_date,
       trunc(months_between(sysdate, hire_date) / 12) as years,
       trunc(mod(months_between(sysdate, hire_date) , 12)) as remaining_months,
       TRUNC(SYSDATE) - ADD_MONTHS(hire_date, trunc(months_between(sysdate, hire_date)))
         AS remaining_days
FROM   employees;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE employees (employee_id, last_name, hire_date) AS
SELECT 1, 'Alice', DATE '2022-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Beryl', DATE '2020-11-30' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Carol', DATE '2000-04-13' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| EMPLOYEE_ID | LAST_NAME | HIRE_DATE | YEARS | REMAINING_MONTHS | REMAINING_DAYS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Alice | 01-JAN-22 | 0 | 11 | 12 |
| 2 | Beryl | 30-NOV-20 | 2 | 0 | 13 |
| 3 | Carol | 13-APR-00 | 22 | 8 | 0 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/pDqPqUXg)